# Which potentials are suitable for molecular dynamics simulation of simple explicit solvents?

Tags: computational-chemistry, intermolecular-forces, solvents

Which potentials ([force fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_field_(chemistry))) are suitable for adequately simulating (mixtures of) explicit solvents? Interesting rheological properties include viscosity, surface tension, heat capacity.

Comment: I would look at polarizable force fields like AMBER/GAFF or CHARMM.

Comment: If you are still interested in this, it would probably be a good fit on the new Matter Modeling SE.